# MEAN & Geospatial queries - Find LineStrings Intersecting on Another One given Its Name

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, google-maps-api-3, mongoose

I'm trying to build an application using **MEAN** but now I'm stuck when trying to `find linestrings intersecting on another one given its name`.

For instance, given the following image, `poly1` and `poly2` should have intersections while `poly3` does not.

[image]

Let's suppose `poly1` has the following coordinates and the following `JSON`:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("57ab2107505ab11b1bd8422e"), 
  "name" : "poly1", 
  "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-08-10T12:41:43.789+0000"), 
  "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-10T12:41:43.780+0000"), 
  "geo" : {
      "coordinates" : [ [14.59, 24.847], [28.477, 15.961] ], 
      "type" : "LineString"
  }, 
  "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

When I run the query on `MongoChef` I find both `poly1` and `poly2` and I do not find `poly3` like I want:

```
{
    geo :{
        $geoIntersects:{
            $geometry :{
                type: "LineString" ,
                coordinates: [ [14.59, 24.847], [28.477, 15.961] ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While, when I run the query on `Mongoose` given a `Polyline Id/name` it does not work

```
//Given
var linestringById = Linestrings.find({name : lineName});
var linestrings    = Linestrings.find({});    

//Works
query = linestrings.where({ geo : { $geoIntersects : 
                    { $geometry : 
                       { type : 'LineString', 
                         coordinates : [ [27.528, 25.006], [14.063, 15.591] ]
                        } 
                     } } });

//Does not work
query = linestrings.where({ geo : { $geoIntersects : 
                   { $geometry : 
                     { type : 'LineString', 
                       coordinates : linestringById.geo.coordinates
                     } 
                    } } });
//Also does not work:
query = linestrings.where({ geo : { $geoIntersects : 
                   { $geometry : 
                     { type : 'LineString', 
                       coordinates : linestringById
                     } 
                    } } });
```

This is the **Schema for LineStrings**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

// Creates a LineString Schema.
var linestrings = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required : true},
    geo : {
        type : {type: String, default: "LineString"},
                coordinates : Array
    },
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

// Sets the created_at parameter equal to the current time
linestrings.pre('save', function(next){
    now = new Date();
    this.updated_at = now;
    if(!this.created_at) {
        this.created_at = now
    }
    next();
});

linestrings.index({geo : '2dsphere'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('linestrings', linestrings);
```

This is how I call the query from the front-end **QueryController.js**

```
/** Looks for LineStrings intersecting a given linestring **/
vm.polyIntersect = function () {

   //Taking name from a form
   vm.queryBody = {
                    name : vm.formData.poly1
   };

   // Post the queryBody 
   $http.post('/find-poly-intersection', vm.queryBody)
             .success(function(queryResults) {
                console.log(queryResults);
             })
            .error(function(queryResults) {
                console.log('Error: no results found '+queryResults));
            });
};
```

This is my **Route.js**:

```
/** Requiring Factories **/
var LinestringFactory = require('./factories/linestring.factory.js');

module.exports = function(app) {
  // Retrieves JSON records for all linestrings intersecting a given one
    app.post('/find-poly-intersection', function(req, res) {
        LinestringFactory.findIntersections(req).then( function (linestrings) {
            return res.json(linestrings);
        }, function (error) {
            return res.json(error);
        })
    });
}
```

This is my **LineString.factory.js**:

```
var Linestrings  = require('../models/linestring-model.js');

exports.findIntersections = findIntersections;

/** Finds Linestrings Intersections **/
function findIntersections(req) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        var lineName       = req.body.name;
        var linestringById = Linestrings.find({name : lineName});
        var linestrings    = Linestrings.find({});

        //Check if that certain linestring exists with Lodash
        if (_.isEmpty(linestringById) || _.isUndefined(linestringById) 
            || _.isNull(linestringById)){
            return reject('No Linestrings found for that Name');
        } else {

        query = linestrings.where({ geo : 
                { $geoIntersects : { $geometry : 
                  { type : 'LineString', 
                    coordinates : linestringById.geo.coordinates} 
                } } });

        query.exec(function (err, intersections) {
            if (err){
                return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve(intersections);
        });

    }, function (error) {
        return reject(error);
    })
}
```

> `console.log` in `QueryController` gives me always `Object {}` for any
>   linestring name.
>
> [This is the Mongoose Log of the query](https://gist.github.com/AndreaM16/1852e3c87eba610020ddf0d107b90191).
>
> I'm making sure of inserting `[lng, lat]` coordinates

**Have you any idea on why I can't find any LineString intersecting by Id while I can find them using straight coordinates?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this issue with the following code

```
/** Finds Linestrings Intersections **/
function findIntersections(req) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        var lineName = req.body.name;
        Linestrings.findOne({name : lineName}).then( function (linestringById, error) {
            if(error){
                return reject({error : 'LineString not Found'});
            }
                queryIntersections(linestringById).then( function (response) {
                    return resolve(response);
                });
        });
    }, function (error) {
        return reject({error : 'Error while executing promise'});
    });
}

function queryIntersections(linestringById) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        if (_.isEmpty(linestringById) || _.isUndefined(linestringById) || _.isNull(linestringById)){
            return reject({ error : 'No Linestrings found for that Name'});
        } else {
            query = Linestrings.where( { geo : { $geoIntersects : { $geometry : { type: 'LineString', coordinates: linestringById.geo.coordinates  } } } } );
            queryExec(query).then( function (intersections) {
                return resolve(intersections);
            });
        }
    }, function (error){
       return reject({error : 'Error while executing promise'});
    });
}
```

The error was caused by the fact that I did not pass correctly `linestrings` and `linestringById` objects to the query.

I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing linestring.geo.coordinates in latitute,longitute format to the final query.
Mongodb accepts coordinates in the x,y format, hence it has to be `longitude,latitude`

Updated:

You will need to directly pass the linestring as $geometry.

```
query = linestrings.where({ geo : { $geoIntersects : 
                   { 
                       $geometry : lineStringbyId.

                    } } });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You mean, I should insert `[lng, lat]` when posting a new linestring? I think I do not need to change the code for that purpose.

Comment: Still empty Object. This is the `Mongoose Log` https://gist.github.com/AndreaM16/1852e3c87eba610020ddf0d107b90191

Comment: Any Idea? @DhruvPathak